# What exactly are the reasons for "the road of excess leads to the palace of wisdom?"

Tags: philosophy-of-mind

Empirical facts seem to support this connection: the Greeks were anything but modest, and among the Greeks, the Athenians were the most extravagant.

I wonder what exactly are the reasons behind this connection.

Answer (score 1):

What does the phrase have to do with the Greeks? And the Greeks had "Nothing in excess" as a proverb.

---

[Wikipedia says](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Marriage_of_Heaven_and_Hell) of the phrase (which was written by Blake, as one of the "Proverbs of Hell"),

> Unlike that of Milton or Dante, Blake's conception of Hell begins not
>   as a place of punishment, but as a source of unrepressed, somewhat
>   Dionysian energy, opposed to the authoritarian and regulated
>   perception of Heaven.
>
> In the most famous part of the book, Blake reveals the Proverbs of
>   Hell. These display a very different kind of wisdom from the Biblical
>   Book of Proverbs. The diabolical proverbs are provocative and
>   paradoxical.
>
> Blake explains that,
>
> > "Without Contraries is no progression. Attraction and Repulsion,
> >     Reason and Energy, Love and Hate are necessary to Human existence.
> >     From these contraries spring what the religious call Good & Evil. Good
> >     is the passive that obeys Reason. Evil is the active springing from
> >     Energy. Good is Heaven. Evil is Hell."

---

For what it's worth, to the extent that it's true, the phrase reminds me of [the "Middle Way" of Buddhism](http://www.sacred-texts.com/bud/btg/btg17.htm); i.e. that you might (as the Gautama Buddha himself did, with his early life as a worldly prince followed by  his striving for enlightenment as an ascetic) know extreme (excess) before you know wisdom (sufficiency); e.g. you know "not enough" and "too much" (excess) before you understand "enough".

> "There are two extremes, O bhikkhus, which the man who has given up
>   the world ought not to follow-the habitual practice, on the one hand,
>   of self-indulgence which is unworthy, vain and fit only for the
>   worldly-minded and the habitual practice, on the other hand, of
>   self-mortification, which is painful, useless and unprofitable.
>
> "Neither abstinence from fish and flesh, nor going naked, nor shaving
>   the head, nor wearing matted hair, nor dressing in a rough garment,
>   nor covering oneself with dirt, nor sacrificing to Agni, will cleanse
>   a man who is not free from delusions. Reading the Vedas, making
>   offerings to priests, or sacrifices to the gods, self-mortification by
>   heat or cold and many such penances performed for the sake of
>   immortality, these do not cleanse the man who is not free from
>   delusions. Anger, drunkenness, obstinacy, bigotry, deception, envy,
>   self-praise, disparaging others, superciliousness and evil intentions
>   constitute uncleanness; not verily the eating of flesh.
>
> "A middle path, O bhikkhus avoiding the two extremes, has been
>   discovered by the Tathagata-a path which opens the eyes, and bestows
>   understanding, which leads to peace of mind, to the higher wisdom, to
>   full enlightenment, to Nirvana! What is that middle path, O bhikkhus,
>   avoiding these two extremes, discovered by the Tathagata-that path
>   which opens the eyes, and bestows understanding, which leads to peace
>   of mind, to the higher wisdom, to full enlightenment, to Nirvana? Let
>   me teach you, O bhikkhus, the middle path, which keeps aloof from both
>   extremes. By suffering, the emaciated devotee produces confusion and
>   sickly thoughts in his mind. Mortification is not conducive even to
>   worldly knowledge; how much less to a triumph over the senses!

Comment: Thanks, @ChrisW. Were not philosophy, mathematics, science, theatre, literature and Art just some of the Greek's indulgences?

Answer (score 0):

Excess do leads to wisdom if used right.

If you are living grand you have more data available to you. Living in a palace you encounter more things and more people than living in a cottage in a village.

Your palace would have population of an entire village living in it out of necessity to have servants to run this large place. You would have an entire other village's population as guards.

You will have more visitors. You can accomodate more guests. You can have large family of your own, like a sheikh, have large extended family living with you permanently.

You can have more friends.

On daily basis you encounter more things and more variety of things. Furniture, clothings, jewellery etc.

Thats half the requirement of wisdom. Have more to ponder on. More data.

Second half is to actually do ponder on them. Being rich you would have more time to think. You can survive with what you have for 100 years if you dont make a penny any more. There are no pressing, urgent needs of survival to keep you busy.

Now, you can use all these resources wrongly. You can indulge in pure pleasure seeking and thus waste it all.